# Golang Join array interface

Tags: mysql, go, slice, variadic, go-gorm

I try to create bulk insert. I use gorm [github.com/jinzhu/gorm](http://github.com/jinzhu/gorm)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    dB "github.com/edwinlab/api/repositories"
)

func Update() error {
    tx := dB.GetWriteDB().Begin()
    sqlStr := "INSERT INTO city(code, name) VALUES (?, ?),(?, ?)"
    vals := []interface{}{}

    vals = append(vals, "XX1", "Jakarta")
    vals = append(vals, "XX2", "Bandung")

    tx.Exec(sqlStr, vals)

    tx.Commit()

    return nil
}
```

But I got an error:

> Error 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 becuse i return wrong query
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO city(code, name) VALUES ('XX1','Jakarta','XX2','Bandung', %!v(MISSING)),(%!v(MISSING), %!v(MISSING))
> ```

If I use manual query it works:

```
tx.Exec(sqlStr, "XX1", "Jakarta", "XX2", "Bandung")
```

It will generate:

```
INSERT INTO city(code, name) VALUES ('XX1', 'Jakarta'),('XX2', 'Bandung')
```

The problem is how to make array interface to generate string like `"XX1", "Jakarta", ...`

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you mean that.. you want to insert two data using one query?

Comment: yes i want insert multiple data at once my reference is http://stackoverflow.com/a/21112176/2486312

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass elements of a slice to a function with variadic parameter, you have to use `...` to tell the compiler you want to pass all elements individually and not pass the slice value as a single argument, so simply do:

```
tx.Exec(sqlStr, vals...)
```

This is detailed in the spec: [Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

[`Tx.Exec()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx.Exec) has the signature of:

```
func (tx *Tx) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (Result, error)
```

So you have to pass `vals...`. Also don't forget to check returned error, e.g.:

```
res, err := tx.Exec(sqlStr, vals...)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks it work is my fault i think ... only sample :|