# How to invoke methods with variant interface when you have array of interface?

Tags: go

how to invoke a method with below signature

```
SomeFunc( args ...interface{})
```

with variable of type `[]interface{}` Is it possible to invoke the above method? If yes how?

Thanks

Comment: There's not a lot of information to go on here, but if I understand correctly you should be able to just call the function and pass it your two arguments. https://play.golang.org/p/ZUPbJYYCt7

Comment: Actually my comment above may not work in your specific case. The issue is that you've named the function starting with a lowercase letter which in Go means that it's a private function and is only available within its own package. You should start any publicly accessible functions (any functions that will be invoked outside of the current package) with a capital letter - for example: `SomeFunc`

Comment: @Mike thanks , but your code is taking the interface array as a single interface in the SomeFunc method https://play.golang.org/p/9dK4QjmW0U

Comment: Variadic arguments are collapsed into a single array of values regardless of how many arguments are passed. Here's another example which passes two separate values. https://play.golang.org/p/vvsfgSAk57 I added the `#` formatter to show the Golang representation of the object. You can index into the argument array as you would any other array, for example `args[0]` extracts the first value.

Comment: Yes that is the issue I am facing

Comment: @Mike invoking like this solved the problem SomeFunc(a, b...)

Comment: Glad you found something that worked for you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpacking slice of slices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914447/unpacking-slice-of-slices/39915311#39915311); and [Golang Join array interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125024/golang-join-array-interface/36125119#36125119).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func main() {
    b := []interface{}{"hello", "Hi"}
    SomeFunc(b...) 
}
```

Solved the issue by using `...` after b array. 
For more details plz see [Unpacking slice of slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914447/unpacking-slice-of-slices/39915311#39915311) and [Golang Join array interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125024/golang-join-array-interface/36125119#36125119)