# Goroutines and Mysql max connections

Tags: mysql, go, goroutine

When I run functions in parallel that make use of mysql driver(Gorm), I find that when I set the following:
     db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(30)
     db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)

I get a clean output without any panics/error messages.

My database server variable for max_connection is set 100. I find if I SetMaxOpenConns to 50 or above I start to receive

```
[mysql] 2017/01/25 14:26:09 packets.go:33: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60614->127.0.0.1:3306: read: connection reset by peer
[mysql] 2017/01/25 14:26:09 packets.go:130: write tcp 127.0.0.1:60614->127.0.0.1:3306: write: broken pipe
```

If I just print the error and not panic then the errors eventually go away and the script finishes processing.

I'm having a tough time understanding how to manipulate these values. The Max Open connWhy when the open connections rate is lower that the script seems to have no problem connecting/reading but a higher max below the server limit is problematic.

MariaDB Version: 10.1.21
Go version: 1.7.4
There are 2.1m records in the csv file that I'm parsing.
I'm batching 2000 records into each insert string

Here is a portion of the main code

```
func main(){
    //Setup and Connect to database 
    //Set variables
    //Read CSV File
    dbConnect()
    defer db.Close()
    db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(30)
    db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)
    db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Second * 14400)
    filehandle, err := os.Open(physicianCSV)
    checkErr(err)
    defer filehandle.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(filehandle)
    _, err = reader.Read()
    checkErr(err)

    for i := 0; i <= readLimit; i++ {
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        }
        physician = convertCSVRecordToPhysician(record)
        //..Do stuff with physician, edit struct properties

        physicians = append(physicians, physician)

        if math.Mod(float64(i), float64(bulkAmount)) == 0 && i != 0 {
            fmt.Println(i, "Records: From ", i-bulkAmount, "to", i)
            wg.Add(1)
            sliceOfPhys := make([]Physician, bulkAmount)
            copy(sliceOfPhys, physicians)
            go bulkSavePhysicians(sliceOfPhys)
            physicians = physicians[:0]

        }
    }

    fmt.Println(readLimit, "records inserted")
    wg.Wait()
}

func bulkSavePhysicians(_physicians []Physician) {
    defer func() {
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }()
    defer wg.Done()

    sqlStringArray := buildSQLStatements(_physicians)
    batchSQL := fmt.Sprintf("insert into physicians values %s ;", strings.Join(sqlStringArray, ","))
    tx := db.Begin()
    errors := tx.Exec(batchSQL).GetErrors()
    if len(errors) > 0 {
        panic(errors)
    }
    tx.Commit()
}

func buildSQLStatements(_physicians []Physician) []string {

    var valueStr string
    var valueArr []string
    for _, phys := range _physicians {

        valueStr = fmt.Sprintf(`( "%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s" )`, phys.NPI,
            phys.PACID,
            phys.ProfessionalEnrollmentID,
            strings.Replace(phys.LastName, "'", "\\'", -1),
            phys.FirstName,
            phys.MiddleName,
            phys.Suffix,
            phys.Gender,
            phys.Credential,
            strings.Replace(phys.MedicalSchoolName, "'", "\\'", -1),
            phys.GraduationYear,
            phys.PrimarySpecialty,
            phys.SecondarySpecialty1,
            phys.SecondarySpecialty2,
            phys.SecondarySpecialty3,
            phys.SecondarySpecialty4,
            phys.AllSecondarySpecialties,
            strings.Replace(phys.OrganizationLegalName, "'", "\\'", -1),
            phys.GroupPracticePACID,
            phys.NumberOfGroupPracticeMembers,
            strings.Replace(phys.Line1StreetAddress, "'", "\\'", -1),
            phys.Line2StreetAddress,
            phys.MarkerOfAddressLine2Suppression,
            phys.City,
            phys.State,
            phys.ZipCode,
            phys.PhoneNumber,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationCCN1,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationLBN1,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationCCN2,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationLBN2,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationCCN3,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationLBN3,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationCCN4,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationLBN4,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationCCN5,
            phys.HospitalAffiliationLBN5,
            phys.ProfessionalAcceptsMedicareAssignment,
            phys.ReportedQualityMeasures,
            phys.UsedElectronicHealthRecords,
            phys.ParticipatedInTheMedicareMaintenance,
            phys.CommittedToHeartHealth,
            phys.SpecialtyID)

        valueArr = append(valueArr, valueStr)
    }
    return valueArr
}
```

Comment: `connection reset by peer` suggests mysql server is closing a tcp connection the go client is trying to read from. Please add versions of mysql & go. Can you post code that will reproduce the issue? How many requests are sent? How many concurrent requests? Does the error happen after some period of time or immediately?

Comment: Seems like higher number of connections is hitting some resource limit. Is the code checking every possible error in all cases? For example, `tx := db.Begin()` can throw an error and if not handled, can lead to read/write errors. Also in the code, when panicking, the Tx is not rolled back so the underlying connection will be left open. It's unusual to panic & recover like that, just rollback and return instead. `tx.Exec(batchSQL).GetErrors()` is odd - what driver is used? Could [LOAD DATA](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#load-data-local-infile-support) be used instead?

Comment: How long does the process usually take to insert all 2m records?

Comment: I edited the code to rebuild the csv then used LOAD Data query in mariadb console. It took ~35 minutes. Thank you for the LOAD DATA link as It says that connection losses can be affected by max-allowed-packet limits. The limit on my server was the default 16MB. I Increased the limit 10 150MB. I was then able to raise the number of open connections to 50 without errors. The memory usage exceeds 1GB though which I will tackle next with some profiling.

Comment: More than about 5 connections may be slow if inserting to one table on one disk, because the connections all compete for the same resource. Fewer connections means less contention, so try reducing the number of goroutines to 5. The max-allowed-packet permits the size of a single insert statement, various sizes of inserted data may explain why error was sporadic. Alternative to increasing max-allowed-packet is reducing insert batch count. Also, consider turning off auto commit is off before bulk inserts.

Comment: Alternative to bulk sql string is a prepared statement with multiple values, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108084/golang-mysql-insert-multiple-data-at-once).