# Bulk MySQL Inserts are 2x Slower than PHP

Tags: mysql, go

I've been testing Go in hopes to use it for a new site and wanted to make sure it was as fast or faster than PHP. So I ran a basic test doing bulk inserts in Go and PHP because I'll need bulk inserts.

My tests used transactions, prepared statements, the same machine, the exact same table definition, no index but the PK, and the same logic in the function.

Results:

- 100k Inserts in PHP (mysqli) was 4.42 seconds
- 100k Inserts in Go (Go-MySQL-Driver) was 9.2 seconds

The go mysql driver i'm using is the most popular one 'Go-MySQL-Driver' found here: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if my code in go is not set up right or if this is just how go is.

The functions add a bit of variability to a few of the row variables just so every row isnt the same.

Go Function:

```
func fill_table(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, result_string *string, num_entries_to_add int) {
    defer recover_show_error(result_string)

    db := getDBConn()
    defer db.Close()

    var int_a int = 9  
    var int_b int = 4  

    var int_01 int = 1           
    var int_02 int = 1451628000 // Date Entered  (2016-1-1, 1am)
    var int_03 int = 11         
    var int_04 int = 0
    var int_05 int = 0

    var float_01 float32 = 90.0 // Value
    var float_02 float32 = 0
    var float_03 float32 = 0

    var text_01 string = "" 
    var text_02 string = ""
    var text_03 string = ""

    start_time := time.Now()

    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stmt, err := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME +
        "(`int_a`,`int_b`,`int_01`,`int_02`,`int_03`,`int_04`,`int_05`,`float_01`,`float_02`,`float_03`,`text_01`,`text_02`,`text_03`) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    var flip int = 0
    for i := 0; i < num_entries_to_add; i++ {

        flip = ((int)(i / 500)) % 2
        if flip == 0 {
            float_01 += .1 // add to Value
        } else {
            float_01 -= .1 // sub from Value
        }

        int_02 += 1 // add a second to date.

        _, err = stmt.Exec(int_a, int_b, int_01, int_02, int_03, int_04, int_05, float_01, float_02, float_03, text_01, text_02, text_03)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start_time)
    *result_string += fmt.Sprintf("Fill Table Time = %s</br>\n", elapsed)
}
```

PHP Function:

```
function FillTable($num_entries_to_add){ 

    $mysqli= new mysqli("localhost", $GLOBALS['db_username'], $GLOBALS['db_userpass'], $GLOBALS['database_name']);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno == 0) {

        $int_a = 9; 
        $int_b = 4; 

        $int_01 = 1; 
        $int_02 = 1451628000; // Date Entered  (2016-1-1, 1am)
        $int_03 = 11; 
        $int_04 = 0;         
        $int_05 = 0;         

        $float_01 = 90.0; // Value
        $float_02 = 0;
        $float_03 = 0;

        $text_01 = ""; 
        $text_02 = "";
        $text_03 = "";


        $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);     // This Starts Transaction mode. It will end when you use mysqli->commit();         

        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $GLOBALS['table_name'] . 
            "(`int_a`,`int_b`,`int_01`,`int_02`,`int_03`,`int_04`,`int_05`,`float_01`,`float_02`,`float_03`,`text_01`,`text_02`,`text_03`) " . 
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $start_time = microtime(true);

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiidddsss', $int_a, $int_b, $int_01, $int_02, $int_03, $int_04, $int_05, $float_01, $float_02, $float_03, $text_01, $text_02, $text_03);

            $flip = 0;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_entries_to_add; $i++) {
                $flip = ((int)($i / 500)) % 2;
                if ($flip == 0) {
                    $float_01 += .1;    // add Value
                }
                else {
                    $float_01 -= .1;    // sub Value
                }

                $int_02 += 1;       // add a second to date.

                $stmt->execute(); //Executes a prepared Update 
            }

            $mysqli->commit();  // Transaction mode ends now    
            $stmt->close();  //Close statement
        }

        $execute_time = microtime(true) - $start_time;
        echo $GLOBALS['html_newline'] . $GLOBALS['html_newline'] . 
            'FillDataEntryTable Speed: '.$execute_time.' sec' . $GLOBALS['html_newline'] . $GLOBALS['html_newline'];

        $thread_id = $mysqli->thread_id;    // Get MySQL thread ID
        $mysqli->kill($thread_id);          // Kill MySQL Server connection
        $mysqli->close();                   // Close MySQL Server connection
    }        
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to show the PHP code as well?

Comment: maio290 - No prob, added it. For some reason the last curly brace doesn't go into the code though. Someone fixed my go func for me with the same prob.

Comment: Fixed the last curly brace. In Stack Overflow, just indent the line by at least 4 spaces to make it code-formatted. You might like to read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks Bill Karwin

Comment: You are using a single transaction in Go but not in PHP. Also, in PHP bind_param is only called once and not for each row. What happens if you do the same in both languages in this regard?

Comment: Peter - I from what I can tell I think i'm using a single transaction in PHP too because the transaction starts with $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); and ends with $mysqli->commit();. Also, in go I was able to do an initial stmt.Exec(vars) outside the loop to bind the variables and then just a stmt.Exec() inside the loop and it actually seems to have worked besides there not being any documentation that it should work. It did not help the times at all though. If there is another way in golang to bind vars to a statement then change the vars and execute the statement w/out rebinding let me know.

Comment: You should take advantage of go capabilities to distribute the work among many routines and achieve parallelism. Literally, this is the way to go. I do believe you ll get good results.

Comment: mh-cbon - You were right. Running 10 go routines to accomplish the job does seem to reduce the execution time to 2.6s. That's nice but it's odd and messy having to spawn so many go routines to do something like this IMO. While experimenting, there might have been an error in my code that led me to think the number of operations in a transaction had something to do with execution time. But never-mind that - I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing to find what language I want to use for my new website I experimented with php, golang, and java. I don't have much experience with any of the languages so anything I say here could be corrected by someone in the future.

My main test was batch inserts into the mysql database because I'll be needing it for an app.

I wanted to move away from php because it's a non-compiled old scripting language which is slower at many things than golang and java. It's also an awkward syntax for many things. However php mysqli is actually 2x faster than golang for large "transactions" unless you awkwardly spawn many go-routines to divide the work up.

During my testing and research I found out a few things.

The PHP mysqli "transactions" api are probably using some kind of batch operations to get a "transaction" done because mysqli has no separate batch functions and the transactions are quicker than single inserts. But in most other languages transactions don't auto-batch everything and don't even increase the execution time. They are just a mechanism to roll back everything in the transaction if something goes wrong. What increases execution time in other languages is using batches.

But one of the big problems with go mysql interface right now appears to be no real support for batch operations. The closest I got was to jerry rig one and make my own batch operation as pointed out by this post ([golang - mysql Insert multiple data at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108084/golang-mysql-insert-multiple-data-at-once)). Doing this I was able to get the execution time in go from 9.2s to 3.9s without spawning other go routines. But since there's no real support for it the  batch operation only returns a single result set for the first operation of the batch. This is worthless to me because I need to return autoinc Ids for my inserted rows. There were other problems with this setup too that I wont go into.

So lastly I tried java on a tomcat server. Tomcat/java installation is a bit more involved than go but programming in java was so much easier and natural. JDBC is an excellent driver with fulls support for easy batch operations with prepared statements. It did 100k inserts in only 1 sec. It's the clear winner in my book. Plus java syntax is much more natural than golang IMO.