# Bulk insert rows from an array to an sql server with golang

Tags: mysql, sql, go, bulkinsert

I have a list of structs as follows

```
row = [
   {
      "name":<name1>,
      "age" :<age1>,
      "job" :<job1>
   },
   {
      "name":<name1>,
      "age" :<age1>,
      "job" :<job1>
   },
   {
      "name":<name1>,
      "age" :<age1>,
      "job" :<job1>
   },
   etc...
]
```

I want to insert this into an SQL table. So far I was running a loop through the array and inserting each row one by one. But is there any other way by which I can insert all the rows with just one query? I know bulk insert, but my understanding is that, for bulk insert, I will have to import data from an external file. I don't want to do that. How do I use the data from this array and perform bulk insert?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert multiple data at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108084/how-to-insert-multiple-data-at-once)

Answer (score 2):

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Job  string
}

func InsertPeople(db *sql.DB, personSlice []*Person) error {
    var queryString = `INSERT INTO "person_table" (
        "name"
        , "age"
        , "job"
    ) VALUES `

    numOfFields := 3
    params := make([]interface{}, len(personSlice)*numOfFields)
    for i, p := range personSlice {
        pos := i * numOfFields
        params[pos+0] = p.Name
        params[pos+1] = p.Age
        params[pos+2] = p.Job

        queryString += `(?, ?, ?),`
    }

    queryString = queryString[:len(queryString)-1] // drop last comma

    _, err := db.Exec(queryString, params...)
    return err
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is more of a workaround using go to construct the SQL query to insert multiple rows right? I am looking for a more SQLish way. Possibly using something like bulk insert but without reading from a locally stored file.

Comment: Is it possible to create a .txt/.csv like object from the array and use this with a normal SQL BULK INSERT statement? that means, without storing it to local or reading it from local?

Comment: @MuhammedRoshan There isn't out-of-the-box support for bulk inserts in the standard library. You'll have to consult the documentation of the driver that you are using to learn whether or not it supports what you are looking for. For example the `lib/pq` driver for the PostgreSQL database has something like this: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports. But you are using mysql apparently, and what driver no one knows but you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to do any kind of super-optimized bulk insert without placing a file on the server I don't think.

I am not sure if the db library supports it but using the [SQLX extension](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) you can build a single insert statement with named bindvars that go against  a struct.  You can then pass an array of these structs to a method like NamedExec.

Something like this:

```
users := []User{
  {
    Name: "alex",
    Email: "alex@example.com",
   },
   {
    Name: "muhammed",
    Email: "muhammed@example.com",
   },
}

db.NamedExec("insert into users (NAME, EMAIL) values (:Name, :Email);", users)
```